# fetch comma separated value in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Please check below table

```
Code   Name  
-----------
 001   A
 001   B
```

My query is

```
Select Code,Name from TableA
```

But I need records like

```
Code  Name
------------
001    A,B
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike MySQL, `SQL Server` doesn't have a built-in function for this but you can still simulate it by using `CROSS APPLY` and `FOR XML PATH('')`

```
SELECT  a.Code, 
        SUBSTRING(d.[Name],1, LEN(d.[Name]) - 1) AddressList
FROM    
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT Code
            FROM TableA
        ) a
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT [Name] + ', ' 
            FROM TableA AS B 
            WHERE A.[Code] = B.[Code] 
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ) D ([Name]) ;
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6a399/1)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `COALESCE`. The following sample turns this

> Hello
>
> World
>
> It's
>
> Me

into this

> Hello, World, It's, Me

```
DECLARE @test NVARCHAR(2000)
SELECT @test = COALESCE(@test + ', ', '') + Field FROM Sampletable WHERE … AND Field IS NOT NULL
SELECT @test
```

You should be able to adapt this to your sample.